# Error: Cannot find module 'net' nodemailer y VueJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, nodemailer

Cordial saludo!

Tengo una aplicación desde hace unos meses en producción, se me pidió que se agregara una nueva funcionalidad para notificar al usuario sobre notificaciones a través de correo electrónico.

He agregado la dependencia de Nodemailer con `npm i nodemailer`.

Tengo un archivo Javascript llamado `mailer.js` donde tengo la configuración respectiva la cual he probado satisfactoriamente.

El error está cuando quiero hacer uso de este archivo desde mi componente vue (no estoy ejecutando nodemailer del lado del cliente).

Y de esta forma hago la importación en mi componente:

```
import { transporter } from '@/mailer'
```

Este es el error que aparece solo en la consola del navegador:

```
defaultable.js?6987:55 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'net'
at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./node_modules/defaultable sync recursive (app.js:1031), <anonymous>:2:10)
at Object.workaround_require (defaultable.js?6987:49)
at require (defaultable.js?6987:77)
at eval (server.js?663d:9)
at defaulter (defaultable.js?6987:83)
at defaultable (defaultable.js?6987:63)
at good (defaultable.js?6987:174)
at Object.eval (server.js?663d:5)
at eval (server.js:242)
at Object../node_modules/hbo-dnsd/server.js (chunk-vendors.js:5241)
```

Según he leido NodeMailer solo es para el entorno NodeJS, si es así ¿hay alguna forma de solventar este error con alguna otra libreria junto con Nodemailer?

Aquí está el código JS:

```
// import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

export const  transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
    host: "smtp.ucp.edu.co",
    port: port,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'webmaster.development@ucp.edu.co',
      pass: 'password'
    },
  // tls: {
  //   // do not fail on invalid certs
  //   rejectUnauthorized: false
  // }
});


transporter.verify().then( () => { 
  console.log('Ready for send emails')
 } )

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'webmaster.development@ucp.edu.co',
  to: 'webmaster@ucp.edu.co',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

export let  enviar = transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: ¿Quieres utilizar el archivo `mailer.js` que hace uso de `nodemailer` y es el código JS que compartiste en vue.js?

Comment: Así es Benjamín

Comment: No creo que eso funcione pues `nodemailer` es dependencia de `npm` para ejecución en node.js, no para navegador. Además, suponiendo que funcionara, no sería muy seguro pues en el código del cliente se encontraría la lógica para el envío de correos, incluyendo credenciales e información sensible, porporcionando así toda la información necesaria para realizar por ejemplo, una impersonificación y enviar correos válidos de parte de `webmaster.development@ucp.edu.co`

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación Benjamin, que puedo utilizar entonces para lograr el objetivo que quiero?